# NewLine in object summary

Tags: c#, newline, summary

Greetings

When setting a summary for a property / field / method etc.. is it possible to have a newline in it?

```
/// <summary>
/// This is line 1
/// This is line 2
/// </summary>
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

When I set this it shows as on mouse over:

> ```
> bool TestLine
> This is line 1 This is line 2
> ```

But I want it to show as:

> ```
> bool TestLine
> This is line 1 
> This is line 2
> ```

I've tried using `\n` but that doesn't work. Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You want to use some thing like this

```
/// <summary> 
/// Your Main comment 
/// <para>This is line 1</para> 
/// <para>This is line 2</para> 
/// </summary> 
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, what about a blank line?

Comment: @Behzad try using `<para>&nbsp;</para>`.

Comment: In the Visual Studio 2017 IDE, the above "solution" actually displays a lone BLANK LINE between line 1 and line 2 (that is, a newline after line 1 followed by a blank line then line 2)--this is not the same a new line, as the OP requested. Is that a bug in the VS 2017 IDE--or does everyone who up-voted not see that this answer doesn't produce what the OP shows as the desired output?

Comment: That's a new paragraph, not a new line. It feels to me that the documentation syntax is somewhat limiting.

Answer (score 76):

This may be an old thread but I was searching for an anwser while using **Visual Studio 2019**. I wanted paragraph and lines breaks. The following works well for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>parameter name="guidType" options:</para>
/// 0 = SequentialAsString<br />
/// 1 = SequentialAsBinary<br />
/// 2 = SequentialAtEnd<br />
/// </summary>
```

Produces the following:

```
parameter name="guidType" options:

0 = SequentialAsString
1 = SequentialAsBinary
2 = SequentialAtEnd
```

Comment: For VS2019 and on, this answer is technically more correct than the accepted answer.

Comment: You can also just use <br /> just at the end of the line in VS2019. These solutions produce an actual line break and not a new paragraph with an empty line! Thanks

Comment: In Rider, everything behind the <br> tag is not displayed. But ending lines with <para /> works as expected

Comment: Good answer, I would only suggest considering using `<see cref="guidType"/>` for referencing your types

Answer (score 34):

Yes:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Main comment 
/// <para>Line 1</para> 
/// <para>Line 2</para> 
/// </summary> 
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `<para />` to add a new line within summary:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Main comment<para />
/// Line 1<para />
/// Line 2<para />
/// </summary>
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

Looks like:

```
Main comment
Line 1
Line 2
```

Best regards!

Comment: Looks like: `Main comment<br/><br/>Line 1<br/><br/>Line 2`

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest using this formatting if you want multiple lines in the summary without making it complicated. It'll work if you **use the <br /> tag after each line.** (using it anywhere inside the text will make a new line where the tag is also.)

Although, note that if you have a space after the <br /> tag, you would get an extra space one the next line. So you wanna have the same amount of space on each line, so every row it'll be in a straight line.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is line 1<br />
/// This is line 2<br />
/// This is line 3<br />
/// </summary>
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

Comment: First thing I tried before looking a solution because that do not work!

Comment: This does seem to work now. Using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Just a note on this, the "&" character cant be used, it breaks the intellisense.

Answer (score 9):

You can legitimately add para tags, but this actually creates a new paragraph for each new line and the line spacing appears off.
I personally add 1 para around the paragraph and then `br` tags at the end of the lines I wanted a break on, which preserves decent line spacing:

```
/// <summary> 
/// <para>Main comment<br /> 
/// Line 1<br />
/// Line 2</para> 
/// </summary>
public bool TestLine { get; set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, and there's nothing off about the spacing with <para>. What version of VS/.Net are you using?

Comment: HTML tags will be ignored by `summary`, even if they're inside `para` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding this for anyone using Xamarin Studio like I am. I found that none of the above solutions work for me, but this one did:

```
/// <summary>
/// Main summarry line.
/// <para></para>
/// <para></para>
/// Your secondary summary
/// </summary>
```

This gives the following output:

```
Summary  
Main summary line.

Your secondary summary
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swashbuckle (Swagger Web API integration library) then `<para></para>` should be replaced with `<p></p>` and `<br/>` also could be used.

so the following

```
    /// <para>
    ///     Flag1, Flag2
    ///     - bool flags, optional.
    /// </para>
```

becomes

```
    /// <p>
    ///     Flag1, Flag2<br/>
    ///     - bool flags, optional.
    /// </p>
```

The issue is already described here:
[How to add line break to Swashbuckle documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559028/how-to-add-line-break-to-swashbuckle-documentation) - using a special config, domaindrivendev's comment,
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/258 - on `<br/>` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Something I didn't see elsewhere in this thread is that there is a difference between `<para></para>` and `<br></br>`.

`<para>` will add a second newline above the text. So you'll end up with text>empty newline>text.

`<br>` will only add a single newline. So you'll end up with text>text.

So, IMO, br is better for lists and para is better for breaking up lines.