# How to add line break to Swashbuckle documentation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, line-breaks, swashbuckle

I'm generating documentation for an api implemented in Web Api 2 using swagger/swashbuckle.

The only xml documentation tags recognized are the `<summary>`, `<remarks>` and `<param>`.
This means I cannot use `<para>` tag to format my text in new lines or paragraphs, everything is generated as a continuous long paragraph in the Implementation Notes entry of the docs.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to achieve is creating a custom OperationFilter and use the xml documentation tags as explained in :

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/258

Hope this helps

Sam

Comment: Setting this as the accepted answer, it's the more elegant solution.

Comment: Adding the description inside <remarks> tag worked for me

Answer (score 24):

I found that you can just add `<br />` tags to the comments to achieve this.
Adding:

```
/// <br />
```

will cause a line break in the generated documentation.

Comment: In VS 2017 and SwashBuckle.AspNetCore 2.4 it doesn't work- shows literally `<br />`

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: For me this works in VS2017 Preview 2.0 with SwashBuckle.AspNetCore 2.4. BUT: If you place the `<br />` at the end of some text (instead of in a line of its own) then you may NOT add an empty line after that `text<br />` line! In other words: there MUST be text in the line following any `text<br />` or the line break will be ignored. Took me while to find that little detail.

Answer (score 6):

In SwashBuckle.AspNetCore `<br />` and `&lt;br /&gt`([suggested in github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/82#issuecomment-56327207)) do not work.
In `<remarks>` you can specify backslash at the end of line.

For example

```
/// <remarks>
///  before. \
///  after.  
/// </remarks>
```

generates  2 lines

```
before.
after.
```

However I was NOT able to generate multiple lines in `<summary>` section.

Note, If the line has trailing spaces(e.g. `"before. \  "`), backslash will be shown literally in the output.
You can see a few my attempts in https://github.com/MNF/Samples/blob/master/SwashbuckleExample/SwashbuckleExample/Controllers/SwashBuckleTest.cs

Answer (score 5):

None of the posted solutions will work with the newer version of Swagger. If you want a newline separation between your comment lines, you have to add `///` for newline. That makes method comments lengthy but they will be more readable in the Swagger documentation.

```
///  <summary>
/// Comment Line 1
///  
/// Comment Line 2
///  
/// Comment Line 3
///  </summary>
```

Comment: Adding /// extra line works for me. but this is no ideal solution, I am using NSwag.AspNet.Core

Answer (score 4):

As per markdown specification, a new line can be added in remarks by adding a double space (two spaces) to end the line

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio 2019 (.net core 3.1), I'm able to use html remarks.  It can be done all on one line using `<br />`.  I've also tried other html tags such as underline and bold.

```
/// <summary>
    /// test
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks><u>underline</u> "test line 1" <br /><b>Bold</b> "test line 2"  </remarks>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the structure below, both the Swashbuckle UI and the ReDoc UI will work:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Title
/// 
/// <para>Content line 1</para> 
/// <para>Content line 2</para> 
/// <para>Content line 3/</para> 
/// </summary>
```

Important note: Do not ignore the spaces at the end of each line

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If none of the answers worked for you, worked partially in some case like it was with me.

You can use `<br></br>`. Do not use `</br>`. It can break XML sometimes. Visual studio showed bad XML formatting for `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

after a long search i found that *** is for Bold text , i know it s not the same subject but i am pretty sure that will be useful for someone here !

example :

`***400 - BadRequest When any parameter is out of specification.***`