# Some features tag is not working in .NET WebApi with ReDoc

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag, redoc

I had installed Redoc with NSwag package in my WebApi projects. But I found that a lot of features are not working in the output API documents:

1. No line break for the summary and remarks tag
   [image: Sample line break]
2. The tag of Example, code is not showing in the document

> ```
> /// <example>
> /// Example request here
> /// </example>
> ```

Not sure if it should be work if I follow the [tag recommendation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags)?

Because I found that none of the tag is working fine as [Redoc samples](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/) except "Param", "Returns"

*Update:*

I tried the set the remarks like this:

> ```
> /// <remarks>Line1
> /// 
> /// Line2
> /// Line3
> /// </remarks>
> ```

But it had became:

[image]

Comment: `<summary>` is treated as plain text, that's probably why line breaks are ignored. `<remarks>` are Markdown, so you'll need to add 1 or 2 blank lines between the paragraphs because a single line break is handled as line continuation.

Comment: I just tried it but it became text in black box.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like Line2 and Line3 were treated as a code block instead of a paragraph. Can you try other suggestions from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32559028/113116)?